# Change particular div class in kendo grid row template

Tags: kendo-grid

I am running one project where i am using kendo grid row template.
Below is my html grid code:

```html
table id="grid" style="width:100%">
                <colgroup>
                    <col class="photo" />
                    <col class="details" />
                    <col />
                </colgroup>
                <thead style="display:none">
                    <tr>

                        <th>
                            Details
                        </th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:30%">
                     div class="row">
                            <div id="dvImage" class="col-sm-4" style="width:118px">
                                #= imagelink #
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-8" style="width:400px">
                                <span class="name" style="font-size:14px; color:green">#: Link #</span>
                               
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </script>
```

In the above script for div class name "dvImage" for sometimes data is not present so it's still contain those space.

I googled many things and got to know that if we can find this div class in onDataBound event then i can check if this div don't have data then can hide this div for particular row. but when i tried this only for first row i am able to hide the data for other rows still it was containing space.
All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirements correctly if the image doesn't exist then you want the rest of the row details to take up the rest of the space? If this is not correct the please correct me.

Assuming this is the case then you can actually change your template like this:

**Before**

```
 <div id="dvImage" class="col-sm-4" style="width:118px">
 #= imagelink #
 </div>
```

**After**

```
#if(data.imagelink === null || data.imagelink === ""){#
<div class="col-sm-12" style="width:518px">
#} else {#
 <div id="dvImage" class="col-sm-4" style="width:118px">
     #= imagelink #
     </div>
<div class="col-sm-8" style="width:400px">
#}#
```

I have put together a demo for you to look at here: http://dojo.telerik.com/eMiMa/2

(in the demo I have told the grid to hide the photo for every even row and expand the details grid to take up two columns rather than 1 column)

What this change simply does is look at your template and checks to see if the `imagelink` value is valid and if it isn't then it simply expands the detail div for you to take up the maximum space. If the image does exist then it processes the template as normal.

In order to keep the `dimensions` the same the opening div for your next section is contained within the conditional formatting so that it applies the correct spacing for you.

If the requirement is to just hide the entire row then you can move this conditional check to the top of the template and hide the entire row. If this is the desired outcome then I can update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your reply i tried with your solution and there was some syntax missing so i was getting invalid template issue so i matched the syntax and working fine me. Thanks I am upvoting your answer.

Comment: Glad it helped. I fixed the missing brackets. The demo should have worked fine though.